# Not able to understand the behavior of WeakMap in ECMA6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, weakmap

I am facing a weird scenario while playing with WeakMap in ECMA6. I am writing a class which is as follows

```
'use strict';
class WeekMaptest {

    constructor(options){
        console.log("constructor");
        this.weekMap = new WeakMap();
        this._init(options);
    }
    _init(options) {
        console.log("init called");
        var privateProps = {
            name: options.name,
            email: options.email
        };
        this.weekMap.set(this, privateProps);
    }

    getName(){
        return this.weekMap.get(this).name;
    }


}
```

Now calling this class to instantiate an object

```
var obj = new WeekMaptest({name: 'Rohit', email: 'rohit.choudhar@gmail.com'});
```

Here comes the out put

```
console.log(obj.getName());
Output : Rohit

console.log(obj.weekMap.get(obj).name);
Output : Rohit

console.log(obj.weekMap.set(obj).name = 'I mena');
Output : I mena

console.log(obj.weekMap);
Output: WeakMap { name: 'I mena' }

console.log(obj.weekMap.get(obj).name);
Error:
/home/bll/bll-jb/server/lib/ease/testweak.js:35
console.log(obj.weekMap.get(obj).name);
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bll/bll-jb/server/lib/ease/testweak.js:35:33)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

I am not able to get myself clear about this behavior of WeakMap.

Comment: BTW: A `weekMap` would be a calendar ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you confused `set`and `get`.

```
console.log(obj.weekMap.set(obj).name = 'I mena');
```

Entries before this call: obj => obj

Entries after this call: obj => undefined

`set` expects arguments for key and value. You don't provide a value, so this code sets the value of the entry with the key `obj` to `undefined`. Consequently the next call to `obj.weekMap.get(obj)` returns undefined.

Comment: So the question is variable defined using WeakMap inside class are actually not Private?

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary I don't know what you mean by _"variable defined using WeakMap"_.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary If you are referring to `privateProps` then that's a variable that is only visible within  `_init`. But the reference it holds is passed to the outside through the weak map. If you are referring to the weak map then nothing is private there.

Comment: Your explanation about weakMap is correct and I know about closure, but my question is why people are suggesting to make private properties using weakMap? . Thank you for your answer,

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Now I understand what you want to achieve. You would have to declare a weak map outside the class and add your "private" properties with the instance of the class as key, as you already did. When the object is "deleted" (i.e. no longer referenced) the entry in the weak map is removed automatically. With a regular map the entry would remain and therefore the instance cannot be garbage collected, which effectively creates a memory leak.